# How to format a column in excel to show percentage instead of decimals. (90% instead of 0.9) in a data frame using python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, formatting, percentage

i have a set of data that i used a python script to collect. i would like row k to have the format of % instead of a decimal

to see a column in "%" format.

```
 dataset_modified.Range("I2:I1400").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_232\934968835.py in <module>
----> 1 dataset_modified.Range("I2:I1400").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
      2 

AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'Range'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using pandas, if that is the case, then you are using the `Styler` class wrongly, [see documentation](https://tedboy.github.io/pandas/api15.html), as it has no attribute `Range`. Maybe the documentation can give some hints.

Comment: i used the document so i assume i should be using dataset_modified.format(percent["I2:I1400"]) however that still doesn't work. i get 'NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_232\561419286.py in <module>
----> 1 dataset_modified.format(percent ["I2:I1400"])
      2 

NameError: name 'percent' is not defined'

Comment: im new to python so please let me know if you can help as ive hit a dead end and haven't found a solution yet

Comment: i have used  '   dataset_modified.apply(percent["I2:I1400"])    '     Instead.  i have received this output                                                                                                                        NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5092\2821706100.py in <module>
----> 1 dataset_modified.apply(percent["I2:I1400"])
      2 

NameError: name 'percent' is not defined

Comment: Late answer, but did you try 'dataset_modified.iloc[2:1400,]' instead of dataset_modified.Range("I2:I1400")?